# Stata equivalent of SQL's 'over(partition by id)

Tags: stata

I'm a SQL and R user who is just starting to use Stata. I'm trying to find an equivalent Stata program/code of doing the following in SQL:

SQL code:

```
MAX(VAR_A) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS MAX_VAR_A
```

I have tried `foreach` (perhaps wrong for the task) command  but no luck.

Comment: Perhaps `egen max_var_A = max(var_A), by(ID)` but in turn I don't know SQL. `help egen` either way,  To get a better answer, show a simple but realistic example of your data in Stata.

Comment: As you are an `R` user, it might help to say that Nick's `egen` command is equivalent to `group_by(id) %>% mutate(max_var_A = max(var_A))` in `dplyr`.